# Passing build option to qbs project

Tags: qt, qmake, qbs

I have a `qbs` project with some external library dependency. As soon as I don't want to specify this dependency inside project source files, I would rather add it as an argument to console build command.

For example: when using `qmake`, I can specify additional qmake console arguments, like `qmake.exe MyProject.pro MYDEFINE="random text"`, and in the project file I can use this argument inside `.pro` files as `$$MYDEFINE`

How to achieve similar functionality with `qbs`?

Comment: Maybe you can define different products that have the options you need.  And from the command line you can decide which product to build. From the documentation: qbs -f /path/to/project.qbs --products productname qbs.architecture:x86_64

Comment: @0rko, well, this seems to be a possible, yet inconvenient solution for specific case. Due to using svn, I want to avoid creating extra files, or modifying local files (as it is done now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a property in the project, for example:

```
Project {
     property path myCustomLibPath: "unknown-path"

     Product {
          name: "Awesome Program 3000"

          Depends { name: "cpp" }
          cpp.libraryPaths: [project.myCustomLibPath]

     }
}
```

Then set it in the command line args:

`qbs build -f /path/to/project.qbs debug project.myCustomLibPath:/path/to/my/lib`

This even works through qt creator.